# Neo4j APOC trigger on relationship delete

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

In my Spring Data Neo4j application I have implemented test that creates the nodes and relationships. So far everything is working fine.

In order to improve application performance, I'd like to try to use manual indexes for relationship properties.

I have added the following Neo4j APOC triggers that must add and remove relationship properties to/from manuall index:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add('HAS_VALUE_ON_ADD_TO_INDEX', 'UNWIND {createdRelationships} AS r MATCH (d:Decision)-[r:HAS_VALUE_ON]->(ch:Characteristic) 
CALL apoc.index.addRelationship(r, keys(r)) RETURN count(*)', {phase:'after'});

CALL apoc.trigger.add('HAS_VALUE_ON_REMOVE_FROM_INDEX', "UNWIND {deletedRelationships} AS r MATCH (d:Decision)-[r:HAS_VALUE_ON]->(ch:Characteristic) 
CALL apoc.index.removeRelationshipByName('HAS_VALUE_ON', r) RETURN count(*)", {phase:'after'});
```

Once I added these indexes, my test(mentioned above) fails with the following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Error executing triggers {HAS_VALUE_ON_REMOVE_FROM_INDEX=Unable to load NODE with id 3.}; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.exception.TransactionException: Error executing triggers {HAS_VALUE_ON_REMOVE_FROM_INDEX=Unable to load NODE with id 3.}
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SessionFactoryUtils.convertOgmAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:144)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.Neo4jTransactionManager.doCommit(Neo4jTransactionManager.java:324)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:532)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at com.decisionwanted.domain.service.data.DataGeneratorImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe2b32e9.cleanDb(<generated>)
    at com.decisionwanted.domain.DecisionCharacteristicIT.setUp(DecisionCharacteristicIT.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.TransactionException: Error executing triggers {HAS_VALUE_ON_REMOVE_FROM_INDEX=Unable to load NODE with id 3.}
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.transaction.BoltTransaction.commit(BoltTransaction.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.Neo4jTransactionManager.doCommit(Neo4jTransactionManager.java:307)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.DatabaseException: Error executing triggers {HAS_VALUE_ON_REMOVE_FROM_INDEX=Unable to load NODE with id 3.}
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketResponseHandler.handleFailureMessage(SocketResponseHandler.java:83)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.PackStreamMessageFormatV1$Reader.unpackFailureMessage(PackStreamMessageFormatV1.java:470)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.PackStreamMessageFormatV1$Reader.read(PackStreamMessageFormatV1.java:431)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketClient.receiveOne(SocketClient.java:196)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketClient.receiveAll(SocketClient.java:190)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketConnection.receiveAll(SocketConnection.java:203)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketConnection.sync(SocketConnection.java:157)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.ConcurrencyGuardingConnection.sync(ConcurrencyGuardingConnection.java:137)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.PooledSocketConnection.sync(PooledSocketConnection.java:157)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.ExplicitTransaction.close(ExplicitTransaction.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.transaction.BoltTransaction.commit(BoltTransaction.java:73)
    ... 39 more
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it ?

**UPDATED**

I use Spring Boot test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { TestApplication.class })
public class DecisionCharacteristicIT {

    @Test
    public void testRelationshipValueTriggerAndIndex() {
        // test logic
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add your test code?

Comment: I have added the general test declaration. Unfortunately, the test logic uses a ton of different classes and it is really hard to provide.